# Pass parameter from extended class

Tags: java, android

I have:

```
public class More {
    protected Void top(Void... params) {

        String test = "1";

        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyMore extends More {
    protected Void top(Void... params) {

        super.top(params);


        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I pass parameter from MyMore to More? I would like make something like that:

```
public class More {
    protected Void top(Void... params) {

        if(PARAM_FROM_MYMORE){
           String test = "2";
        else {
           String test = "1";
        }

        return null;
    }
}



public class MyMore extends More {
    protected Void top(Void... params) {

        //PARAM_FROM_MYMORE = true ????
        super.top(params);


        return null;
    }
}
```

I know - I can:

```
public class MyMore extends More {
    protected Void top(Void... params) {

        super.top(params);
        String test = "2";

        return null;
    }
}
```

but i use class More in others class etc. I would like pass parameter. This is only example.

Comment: Any example of a situation where that design would be useful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature of top

```
public class More {
    protected Void top(Void... params, boolean cond) {

        if(cond){
                   String test = "2";
        else {
              String test = "1";
         }

                return null;
        }
}
```

And the in MyMore

```
public class MyMore extends More {
        protected Void top(Void... params) {

        super.top(params, true);

        return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: `MyMore.top()` does not override `More.top()`.

Comment: Yes but is this really an issue ?

Comment: If I want to have an array of `More` and `MyMore` objects and call `top()` on each one it is.

Comment: Without a real situation, it's hard to make assumptions